# Adding an "Upgrade Subscription" button to an Elementor page

Tags: php, functions

I'm working on a website with Woocommerce Subscriptions and Elementor Pro. What I'm only trying to achieve is to add an "Upgrade Subscription" button to one of the pages.

Someone has already [gave me an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71216198/17955674) from stackoverflow on how to do this, but I just don't know on how to work on this since I'm still not that good in PHP. This is partial description of my post from [the other website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71208133/creating-an-upgrade-button-for-woocommerce-subscriptions/71216198#71216198):

> The subscription is under a variable product that has Monthly and Yearly options. As far as I know, upgrading a product is different from buying the subscription again with a higher value since the URL for switching has the the additional **"?switch-subscription=XXXX&item=XX&_wcsnonce=XXXXXXXXXX"** included in the address that is uniquely different per user. I just want to know if it's possible to generate the proper URL for subscription switching so that I can add that link to a button, or a better workaround.

I would really appreciate it if someone can guide me with this (especially on how to implement the code in Elementor. Thanks!

Comment: This is the problem with builders like Elementor, you may not have an easy route available to do this.  It's also difficult to add assistance as there isn't a single line of code for anyone here to work with.

Comment: Is it possible to just create a shortcode for this?

Comment: I would imagine so.  You'd have to build your own plugin or add code to your theme's functions.php file, assuming you're using your own theme or a child theme.